# no viable conversion from 'function<char (std::string &)>' to 'function<void (std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>)>

Tags: c++, function, c++11

I am trying to create a lambda function that will apply a particular transformation to a linked list. in order to prepare the conversion function, I tried making this function but I am getting the following error **no viable conversion from 'function<char (std::string &)>' to 'function<void (std::__cxx11::basic_string)>** at line **link_list firstChar = list.map(first_char);** I am pasting the code below for reference.

```
link_list<T> map(std::function<link_list<T>(char &l)> fprint)
    {
        std::ignore =fprint;
    };

 std::function<char(std::string&)> first_char = [](std::string &st) {
        if (st.length() > 0) {
            return st.at(0);
        } else {
            return char(0);
        }
    };

    link_list<char> firstChar = list.map(first_char);
    firstChar.print();
```

Comment: The error message does not seem to match the code, please show a [mre]. `first_char ` is of type `std::function<char(std::string&)>`, but `map` expects a `std::function<link_list<T>(char &l)>` and I'm not sure what you expect to happen.

Comment: The function is supposed to accept a particular input of a type and based on the input type we will return a linked_list of type same as that of input